# Native azure login iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, authentication

I am developing an iOS app and want to implement an Azure B2C login without redirect to a WEB UI, only native using the username and password, facebook or google. How can i do this? It is possible?

Comment: Did you find any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Azure Mobile Apps and authentication by social media (fb, tt, gmail, MS account) or enterprise via Azure Active Directory.

More info here: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/authconcepts/